# Returning shared_ptr in multithreading is safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, race-condition, thread-synchronization

I have just started working in multi-threaded environment with c++.I have doubt in below code snippet.

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeInterface> getSessionLocked(const std::string& token) {
          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_mutex);
           if (!findSessionByToken(token)) {
               return nullptr;
          }
          return m_activeSessions[token]; 
    }
bool findSessionByToken(const std::string& token) {
      return !(m_activeSessions.find(token) == m_activeSessions.end());
 }
```

Both m_mutex and m_activeSessions are private variables.Now my question is that "Is it safe to return shared pointers like this" because i think there might be possibility of data inconsistency because of race conditions. Can someone clear this thing ?

Comment: `m_activeSessions[token]` is a `std::shared_ptr` and `m_mutex` guards `m_activeSessions`?

Comment: I don't see a problem here, why do you think there may be inconsistencies? (I assume `m_mutex` guards `m_activeSessions`).

Comment: You should know that `shared_ptr` will prevent the underlying object from being destroyed. This means that if there any reference lying around there, removing the token from `m_activeSessions` won't destroy the object.

Comment: The `findSessionByToken` function that you added in an edit is _not_ threadsafe, if `m_activeSessions` is a type that can invalidate iterators.

Comment: @ichramm: I'd hope they know that; there's no reason to use `shared_ptr` here except to defer destruction until all references are released (if they didn't want that behavior, they may as well just store `std::unique_ptr` and return references).

Comment: you hand out a pointer to the private member. The caller can now use the pointer without any synchronization. Returning the pointer is fine, shared_ptrs reference count is thread-safe, but that does imply that using the pointed to object is thread safe.

Comment: @DrewDormann: I think the correct solution there is a to make a private `findSessionByTokenUnlocked` that is used by both `getSessionLocked` and `findSessionByToken` (with the latter being a thin wrapper that makes a `lock_guard` on the mutex and otherwise delegates to `findSessionByTokenUnlocked`).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Would't that depend only on whether the pointed object is thread safe an not? I think we have enough information to think that this has something to do with the underlying object's implementation.

Comment: It's worth noting that shared_ptr<> is thread-safe including copy construction and assignment even among instances sharing ownership of the same object. That is more than can be said for standard library objects in general.

Comment: @ichramm not sure. I have seen faulty code where a getter was protected via a mutex and the author was expecting that this automagically makes the object refered to by the returned reference/pointer threadsafe.

Comment: This question may need more clarity - a second function was added, but the question doesn't seem to ask anything about this function.  Some commenters (plus myself) seem unsure if this question is asking whether the return statement itself is threadsafe or if the returned object remains threadsafe.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry, I meant "we don't have enough information". And I agree with you, those assumptions are more common that I would like to admit.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I prefer a `findSessionByToken` that has a default argument that locks or you can pass an argument when things are already locked (e.g. a `std::lock_guard *guard = nullptr`).

Answer (score 1):

This funcion:

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeInterface> getSessionLocked(const std::string& token) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_mutex);
       if (!findSessionByToken(token)) {
           return nullptr;
      }
      return m_activeSessions[token]; 
}
```

is ok because:

1. You don't read from `m_activeSessions` unless you have the lock
2. You return `std::shared_ptr`, so the object won't be destroyed until all reference to this shared pointer go out of scope (even if you remove the token from `m_activeSessions`.

One think that could be better/you need to watch for:

1. Consider the rate #readers / #writers in order to see if you need a reader-writer lock.
2. Consider using `std::weak_ptr` if think it is difficult to track all the different places where the shared pointer might be used.

On the other hand, this function:

```
bool findSessionByToken(const std::string& token) {
    return !(m_activeSessions.find(token) == m_activeSessions.end());
}
```

Is not thread safe (the iterator returned by `find` could be invalidated before the comparison takes place).

Now, in your example the function is called with the lock held so: is this function public or private?

If this is a private function then it's ok, but I would recommend changing the name to reflect that the fact that is not thread safe (something with the `Unlocked` or `Unsafe` suffix).

If this function is public then you have a problem.

Finally, the function returns `bool` so the name should be something like `containsToken` or `containsTokenUnsafe`. The word `find` indicates that you are going to return the session, but you didn't.

A final thought:

Considering this is a multi-threaded app, where concurrent access to shared resources is expected, I would make concurrency a first class citizen an change the nomenclature:

- Change `getSessionLocked` to `getSession`. Not only because the reason above but also because the caller shouldn't care whether you use a lock or not. I mean, how would an external user handle non-protected access to a class private data?
- Make non thread-safe functions at least private (adding the unsafe/unlocked suffix may be a personal preference).

Comment: Thanks for you answer.One more thing why findSessionByToken is thread safe when it is private.Lets say if we have another public method that uses this method and doesn't have lock_gaurd. Then i think findSessionByToken will not be safe even if it is private.

Comment: I don't think I said that, `findSessionByToken` is not thread-safe. However, when you call it with the lock held, it doesn't matter whether it is thread-safe or not because you have already taken care of the synchronization part.